# Заполнение таблиц случайными данными

Tags: sql, sql-server, случайные-числа

SQL Server 2014
Для тестирования бд нужно заполнить рандомными данными.
Какими инструментами можно по быстрому сделать это?
понравился софт http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/
но крякнутая версия старая, SQL Server 2012 и 2014 не поддерживает.

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать скрипт, который в цикле будет использовать функцию RAND:

```
declare @i int =0
while @i<10
begin
select RAND()
set @i=@i+1
end
```

Comment: допустим у меня 50 таблиц, с различными ключами, типами данных...не вариант

Comment: С типами проблем нет, т.к. случайное число можно преобразовать в целое, а его в код символа, например, или дату.

Comment: 50 таблиц, с этим как бороться?)

Comment: А как с этим будет бороться скрипт, который вы ищете?
Если вы хотите создать генератор на все случаи жизни, то 

1. цикл по таблицам

2. цикл по столбцам

3. цикл по строкам